# BreezeJS: Why aren't deletions made in Before/AfterSaveEntitiesDelegate propagated back to the client?

Tags: breeze

I am writing a simple event planning web app (using BreezeJS/Entity Framework) - users create a *tournament* entity, and ask the server to generate one or more suggested *plans* (just one for the purposes of this post).

Whenever the user clicks "generate plan", the tournament (including lots of details needed to generate a plan) should be submitted to the server, the server should delete any existing plan, generate a new one, and the client-side model should be updated.

A perfect fit for a **named save**, I thought!

The problem is the last step: updating the client-side model. The plan entity added by the server appears as expected in the client, but the **deletion is ignored**. I.e. the client ends up with both the new and the old plan!

Here's my named save:

*[**Note:** The description and code in this question omits a lot of irrelevant details (like 20 properties and entity types) to keep the size of the question down]*

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult MyNamedSave(JObject saveBundle)
{
    _contextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate = RecalculatePlan;
    return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}

private Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> RecalculatePlan(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> arg)
{
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517945/using-this-context-inside-beforesaveentity:
    var readonlyContext = new PontifexContext();

    foreach (var eventInfo in arg[typeof(Tournament)])
    {
        var tournament = (Tournament)eventInfo.Entity;

        var deletePlan = readonlyContext.Plans.First(p => p.TournamentId == tournament.Id);
        arg[typeof(Plan)].Add(_contextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(deletePlan, EntityState.Deleted););

        var addPlan = new Plan {TournamentId = tournament.Id, };
        arg[typeof(Plan)].Add(_contextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(addPlan, EntityState.Added););
    }
}
```

Am I trying to use named-saves for something they're not meant to do (i.e. deleting and adding entities)?

PS: I tried doing an explicit addition and save using both readonlyContext and _contextProvider.Context, but that *really* didn't work.

**EDIT:**

If I try to explicitly delete the old plan from the DB like below, nothing happens:

```
        arg[typeof(Plan)].Add(_contextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(deletePlan, EntityState.Deleted););
        // Add this:
        context.PlanEntries.Remove(deletePlan);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm guessing it's because _contextProvider.Context already has the old plan in cache, so deleting it "behind its back" (i.e. using another context) doesn't make a difference.

If I then try removing it using _contextProvider.Context, I get a weird duplicate-entry error from the framework.

I'm at my wits' end!

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the data in the save request and response, as logged by IEs developer tools.

Request first:

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "EventName": "Test Tournament",
            "EventTime": "2015-03-21T20:00:00.000Z",
            "entityAspect": {
                "entityTypeName": "Tournament:#Pontifex.Model",
                "defaultResourceName": "Tournaments",
                "entityState": "Unchanged",
                "originalValuesMap": { },
                "autoGeneratedKey": {
                    "propertyName": "Id",
                    "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "saveOptions": { }
}
```

The server then deletes the existing Plan entry (Id=10), and adds a new (Id=11), which I verified using a SELECT directly in the DB. That is good.

But the response is:

```
[
    {
        "$id": "1",
        "$type": "Pontifex.Model.Tournament, Pontifex.Server",
        "Id": 1,
        "EventName": "Test Tournament",
        "EventTime": "2015-03-21T20:00:00.000",
        "Plans": [
            {
                "$id": "17",
                "$type": "Pontifex.Model.Plan, Pontifex.Server",
                "Id": 11,
                "TournamentId": 1,
                "Tournament": { "$ref": "1" }
            }
        ],
        "BoardPlan": null
    }
]
```

In this response, the deleted entity never appears, so the client understandably leaves it in its model.

The added Plan (Id 11) *does* appear, and is integrated in the client model.

**BUT:** judging from sbelinis answer to [Server added object showing as added in client after save changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16847697/5303042), the fact that the added Plan appears may be a lucky coincidence:

> In your particular example, the new entity made into the save because it happened to be related to the entity of the BeforeSaveEntity method, but you should not rely on it.

But sbelinis example of how to *properly* add an entity appears incomplete (e.g. it refers to a local variable saveMapAdditions which isn't used elsewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to work around this!

I still can't get the deletion reflected back into the client cache...BUT if my server-side code ALSO removes the deleted entity from all relations, the removals WILL be reflected back, and the entity will disappear from the client-side model.

The updated code (I've added the statement `tournament.Plans.Remove(deletePlan)`):

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult MyNamedSave(JObject saveBundle)
{
    _contextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate = RecalculatePlan;
    return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}

private Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> RecalculatePlan(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> arg)
{
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517945/using-this-context-inside-beforesaveentity:
    var readonlyContext = new PontifexContext();

    foreach (var eventInfo in arg[typeof(Tournament)])
    {
        var tournament = (Tournament)eventInfo.Entity;

        var deletePlan = readonlyContext.Plans.First(p => p.TournamentId == tournament.Id);
        arg[typeof(Plan)].Add(_contextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(deletePlan, EntityState.Deleted););

        // Workaround: Remove the deleted plan from all relations:
        tournament.Plans.Remove(deletePlan);

        var addPlan = new Plan {TournamentId = tournament.Id, };
        arg[typeof(Plan)].Add(_contextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(addPlan, EntityState.Added););
    }
}
```

Of course, if you search the client local cache for Plan entities, I suspect the deleted plan will still appear, so it's not perfect. But it works for me!

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer. I'm not sure if this is bad form - padding yourself on the back - but it does describe the solution to my problem...